# What is the purpose of making notes in a Physics degree?

Tags: soft-question, education

I have a general question regarding the importance of taking/making notes in Physics degree.

My issue is this: I feel taking/making notes is taking up way too much of my time, and I feel like I’d be better spending 100% of my time answering questions. The only benefit I’ve found to taking notes is that it helps me pay attention in lectures, but I’ve found that I end up referring to the lecture notes that my university provide anyway.

I have a tendency to be a bit of a perfectionist when it comes to note taking, and my fear is that when I finish my degree, instead of a set of beautifully organised and annotated folders containing everything I’ve learned, I’ll have nothing to show for it besides a bunch of concepts/definitions crammed inside my head, which I will forget in the years to come.

I have seen people make the argument “it is important to put concepts down in your own words”, but if I understand the notes my university provides, is there any point in me writing notes of my own.

I also have a related question concerning selection of practice problems: Is there any point in answering questions that I know I can do, or should every question I attempt be pushing my physics/problem solving skills to the limit (within reason), I am asking this question as I feel there is something to be gained from answering straightforward questions, as it builds familiarity/speed when answering questions.

Ultimately, I want to get high marks in my exams, and finish my degree with a sound understanding of everything I have learned, and since I am coming to the end of my 1st year, what would be the best way for me to approach my 2nd year based on the information I’ve provided to you?

Comment: Opinion-based questions are off-topic here, and a question about how you should study physics is not a question about physics itself.

Comment: This is off topic, but I will comment anyway. I hated to take notes as an undergraduate, so I never did. The textbook was enough. My grades would have been better if I had taken notes. In graduate school, courses were tougher. I quickly learned to take notes. If you study physics, you will learn a bunch of concepts. But also skills in problem solving and generally how to think. Thinking is a skill that needs to be learned. The more you put into it, the more you will get out of it. Do what feels right for you. If you don't like the outcome, change.

Comment: “The h bar” chat room is an appropriate place to discuss and compare study habits.

Comment: @Ghoster - Migrating the question would be appropriate.

Comment: "I’ll have nothing to show for it besides a bunch of concepts/definitions crammed inside my head, which I will forget in the years to come." **Yes, that is why you write stuff down.**

Comment: @mmesser314 *Migrating the question would be appropriate.* The question was already closed at the time you suggested migration. In any case, I don’t have enough rep to vote to close or to migrate, and I don’t know where it would be on-topic.

Comment: *"if I understand the notes my university provides ..."*  It was my own experience that I would think I understood it all from material provided and lectures and then later realize that I did not.  That's why I quickly learned to write my own notes, which helped structure the knowledge in my head my own way.

Comment: @AlexNelson My own experience is that comprehension achieved in real time without taking notes stuck, while notes were just pieces of paper, of little help. Everybody is different.

Comment: For what it's worth, the physical process of writing down notes with my hands greatly improves my comprehension and recall. It doesn't matter whether I ever look at the notes again or not; it is the writing that does the trick.

Comment: "... instead of a set of beautifully organised and annotated folders containing everything I’ve learned ..." For what it's worth, even if your notes were beautifully written and organized, if you continue on to graduate school you will most likely look back at the whole of your undergraduate work and cringe. I had a notebook of what seemed to be profound insights which, in hindsight, were either obvious or flatly incorrect. Thank the gods none of that survived and I never started a blog.

Comment: $\uparrow$ The point of that is not to discourage note-taking, but rather to suggest that you not place too much value on having a library of notes to take pride in after the fact.

Comment: @J.Murray Thank you!! What you just said was extremely insightful and helpful

Answer (score 1):

Everybody is different. Personally, in my student days, I found note taking to be distracting. It worked better for me to concentrate on comprehension in "real time". Others have different experience. There's no universal answer: you need to work this out for yourself.

As for practice problems, I found a good strategy was to try to make my own in the style of the problems I was given. You learn a lot more about what problems have reasonable paper solutions that way.